# Does Falcor support internationalization?

Tags: falcor

I've read through most of the docs, but I can't find any mention of internationalization. Does falcor have a standardized way of supporting internationalization, or is it left to the user to hack in? Take this example from their docs:

```
{
    todosById: {
        "44": {
            name: "get milk from corner store",
            done: false,
            prerequisites: [{ $type: "ref", value: ["todosById", 54] }]
        },
        "54": {
            name: "withdraw money from ATM",
            done: false,
            prerequisites: []
        }
    },
    todos: [
        { $type: "ref", value: ["todosById", 44] },
        { $type: "ref", value: ["todosById", 54] }
    ]
};
```

What do you do if the 'name' properties have multiple values for different language translations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Falcor does not have anything special for internationalization. But why should it? It is a library for data fetching.

If the client should have the ability to retrieve the same field in multiple languages then the different values should probably reside at different paths. For example: `todosById[44].name["en-GB"]`, `todosById[44].name["fr-CH"]`.

Otherwise (if language is negotiated by other means), then you can use your usual way of dealing with internationalization. Falcor is only HTTP with some conventions.

Comment: "But why should it?". I tend to compare things like falcor and graphql to HTTP. HTTP has a well thought out and standardized solution to localization. All else being equal, that is preferable to each endpoint implementing it's own less well thought out and non-standard solution. I'd argue that falcor is NOT http with some conventions. It's RPC.